# Hokuyo_node Dynamically Reconfigure max_range min_range

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all.

I just wondering whether it might be possible to dynamically reconfigure the parameters "max_range" and "min_range" of the hokuyo_node.

As far as I can see in the documentation  http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node

the previous parameters are just read only.

I would like to filter the "min_range" for instance to 0.20, so the laser can filter all readings less than 0.20.

In advance thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80786/hokuyo_node-dynamically-reconfigure-max_range--min_range/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2013-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This feature is a bad idea for a driver.  Filtering based on range does not save bandwidth or processing, so there's no real advantage here.  In fact, there's a real disadvantage if you're logging the data and decide later that you really needed all readings less than 0.15m instead.

It's best to create a node that reads the laser scan, changes it, and republishes it on a different topic.  You can then log /scan and generate new configurations of /scan_range_filtered when you play back bagfiles.

/scan -> /scan_range_filtered

Don't forget to use REP 117 if you change the range values.  http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0117.html

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-09-18**:
First at all, thank you for your replay. I can see that the hokuyo_node has a parameter called 'use_rep_117' it is set true by default, so I guess is to change this value to false with the following command,   'rosparam set use_rep_117 true', right? what do you mean with log /scan?